Subject placement in not only ... but also construction
This is an example taken from cambridge dictionary article not only ... but also:

Not only did she forget my birthday, but she also didn’t even
apologise for forgetting it.

In their example, the subject (she) goes between but and also. Therefore, I guess the following ordering would be wrong:

Not only did she forget my birthday, but also she didn’t even
apologise for forgetting it.

So far so good. However, Cambridge uses the following example earlier in their article:

Not only was it raining all day at the wedding but also the
band was late.

Shouldn't the ordering be:

Not only was it raining all day at the wedding but the band was
also late.

Why in the first example provided by Cambridge the subject (she) goes between but and also, and in the second example the subject (the band) goes after but also? Does this have to do with the fact that in the first example, the subject (she) is the same for both independent clauses?

This is to a degree a style matter rather than a categorically right / wrong issue. 'Not only did she forget my birthday, but also she didn’t even apologise for forgetting it.' is hardly ungrammatical. // That said, I'd avoid 'Not only was it raining all day at the wedding but the band was also late.' The string 'the band was also' is garden-pathy ... what else was the band?

There's also a question of emphasis: "Not only was my mother late but my father was also delayed." While "not only ... but also ... " emphasises that 2 things went wrong more than what the things were.

Why does sentence #1 need but or also when the setup was already Not only? *Not needed at all: "Not only did she X, she didn’t do Y." At most, "Not only did she X, but she didn’t do Y."


(CoGEL § 13.42) Not (only) . ... but
The negator not/n't or the combination not/n't only may be correlative with a following but :

He didn't come to help, but to hinder us.
They not only broke into his office and stole his books, but (they) (also)
tore up his manuscripts.

[…]
The meaning of not only . . . but is essentially additive, like that of both . . . and: it distinguishes rather than equates the conjoins, forcing us to look at the first conjoin as 'given' ground. But with not only . . . but the emphasis is greater, suggesting that the content of the first clause is surprising, and that that of the second clause, often reinforced by an adverb such as also or even, is still more surprising. what particularly makes these combinations resemble correlatives is the option of moving the negative particle out of its normal position following the operator, so as to mark the parallelism between the two conjoins:

Not [Henry], but [his wife] is the owner. [1]
He came not [to help], but [to hinder us]. [2]
Not only [did they break into his office and steal his books], but
[they also tore up his manuscripts].



Not only was it raining all day at the wedding but also the band was late.

In order to reinforce the suggestion that the content of the second clause,  is still more surprising, the adverb "also" must bear on the whole close, and not on the constituent "late".


Not only was it raining all day at the wedding but the band was also late.


In this particular place, right before "late", "also" does not make sense.


Not only was it raining all day at the wedding but the band was not complete, and also late, and has no role in reinforcing the fact that the content of the second clause is even more surprising.


In this last sentence, it is clear that the adverb "also" (here a conjunct) adds greater weight to "late" as an addition to "not complete".
